# how to use VC to operate the date in files of MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, visual-c++

how to use c++(in VC) to operate the date in files of MYSQL ( like *.frm *.MYD *.MYI) without  MySQL server instance？

In my computer ，i doesn't install  a MYSQL database systems;So there no  MySQL server instance.

And there are some date files of MYSQL ( like *.frm *.MYD *.MYI) ,which i want to operate.

is there any documents about the structure of these data files ( like *.frm *.MYD *.MYI)？？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual C?

You do NOT want to mess with the raw MySQL files. You'd have to duplicate MySQL's own file handling code exactly, and you're very likely to corrupt the files.

MySQL is open source, you can trivially get the code which is **THE** source for documentation about the file formats, but again - don't deal with the raw files.